# Image is not opening after converting with aspose

Tags: c#, webrequest, aspose, aspose.words

I used the below code to convert url stream into tiff image. But after conversion, the convert image is not opening for preview. Any Ideas?

```
var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");

myRequest.Method = "GET";

var myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
var responseStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

responseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

var loadOptions = new LoadOptions();

loadOptions.LoadFormat = LoadFormat.Html;

var doc = new Document(memoryStream, loadOptions);
var htmlOptions = new HtmlFixedSaveOptions();

htmlOptions.ExportEmbeddedCss = true;
htmlOptions.ExportEmbeddedFonts = true;
htmlOptions.ExportEmbeddedImages = true;
doc.Save(@"C:\out.tif", htmlOptions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using HtmlFixedSaveOptions in Save() method, so it will save as HTML. Try to open the out.tif in any text editor, you will see HTML tags.

Please use ImageSaveOptions in Save() method, to save in image format. Even then, if you manually get the web page from URL in stream, it only gets the HTML. Without css, the saved image will not look good. I would recommend to let Aspose handle the URL.

```
// If you provide a URL in string, Aspose will load the web page
var doc = new Aspose.Words.Document("http://www.google.com");
// If you just provide the TIF extension, it will save as TIFF image
doc.Save(@"c:\out.tif");
// TO customize, you can use save options in save method
```

I work for Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thats great! Thanks! Great to hear that your Aspose Developer